# Не-const-метод в конструкторе при создании const-экземпляра

Tags: c++

Почему если мы создаем `const`-экземпляр класса и в конструкторе вызываем функцию-член этого класса, в сигнатуре которой нет `const` -- все хорошо? Веедь к моменту исполнения тела конструктора экземпляр класса уже создан?

```
class X
{
public:
    X(...) : ...
    {
        f(); // ok
    }

    void f()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

const X x; // ok

x.f() // error
```

Comment: Это логично - откуда конструктору знать, вызывается он на константном объекте или нет?

Comment: @int3 Вроде как на этот счет было предложение разрешить конструкторы и деструкторы с `const` и `volatile` квалификаторами, по аналогии с обычными методами.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` `volatile` квалификаторы начинают применяться к объекту только после завершения конструктора:

> **15.1 Constructors [class.ctor]**
>   3 A constructor can be invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. `const` and `volatile` semantics (10.1.7.1) are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (6.6.2) ends.

Comment: действительно, чтобы можно было определить обьект  как неизменяемый, сначала нужно создать обьект...